# Ajax não recebe dados em json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Pessoal eu criei uma função com Ajax que deve retorna as postagens que estão no banco de dados. O Ajax requisita a um script PHP que o mesmo responde com um JSON porém eu recebo a seguinte mensagem no console do navegador

> XMLHttpRequest síncrono não deve ser usado na thread principal devido
>   a seus efeitos prejudiciais para a experiência de usuário. Para mais
>   informações http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

Segue o código front-end:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
    var value = 4;
    function getOtherPubli() {
        var stringUrl = $(location).attr('href').split("/");
        var type = stringUrl[2];
        var id = stringUrl[3];
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/sys/etc/other-publi.php",
            data: {noPost: id, q: value, b: count, type: type}

        }).done(function (answer) {
            if (answer.status == 'ok') {
                $('contant-others-publi').html(answer.string);
                count += value;
            } else {
                console.log("System (other post) error. Code: " + answer.status);
            }


        }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            console.log("System (other post) error. Request failed: " + textStatus);

        });
    }
    getOtherPubli();
});
```

Código em PHP:

```
<?php

include_once 'sys/lib.php';
include_once 'sys/db/base0.php';

$id = [];
$tl = [];
$cp = [];
$string = '';
$res = ['status'=>null,'string'=>null];

if (isAjax()) {
    $getPost = ["nopost" => (int) $_POST['noPost'], "q" => (int) $_POST['q'], "b" => (int) $_POST['b'], "type" => clrSqli($_GET['type'])];
    $db = connectdb();
    $get = $db->prepare("SELECT id,title,coverofpost FROM `posts` WHERE id <> :notPost AND type = :type ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT :begin, :end");
    $get->bindValue(":notPost", $getPost['nopost'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $get->bindValue(":begin", $getPost['q'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $get->bindValue(":end", $getPost['b'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $get->bindValue(":type", $getPost['type'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $get->execute();
    if ($get->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($data = $get->fethc(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            array_push($id, $data['id']);
            array_push($tl, $data['title']);
            array_push($cp, $data['coverofpost']);
        }
        $length = count($id);
        for ($i = 0;$i < $length;$i ++) {
            $string .= '<div class="other-publi" data-id="'.$id[$i].'">
                        <div class="limit-img-other-publi">
                            <img class="img-other-post" src="'.$cp[$i].'" alt="FOTO"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title-other-publi">
                            <span>'.$tl[$i].'</span>
                        </div>
                     </div>';
        }
        $res['status'] = 'ok';
        $res['string'] = $string;
    } else {
        $res['status'] = 404;
    }
} else {
    $res['status'] = 403;
}
echo json_encode($res,true);
```

Comment: Esse erro não tem a ver com o código que colocaste. Tens mais alguma chamada ajax? ou falta alguma coisa que não colocaste na pergunta? Esse erro que dá diz em que linha o problema está?

Comment: Esse erro é exibido com referencia a "jquery.min.js:4:16013". É simplesmente isso uma requisição ajax para o php que deveria retonar o json. Inclusive acabei de verificar aqui o objeto e ele não existe retorna "undefined".

Comment: Primeiro, sugiro que faça um teste de requisição pra sua api usando um [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) da vida, só pra testar o que retorna na requisição.

Comment: Esse ajax não tem mais parametros de configuração? não tens um `ajaxSetup` algures?

Comment: Desculpa pelo o inconveniente

Comment: Como você tinha dito Sergio a mensagem de erro não tem nada haver com o código. E o fato do json está indefinido é porque os parâmetros que estão sendo passados estão errados. Quando consultado na base retorna zero rows. Está resolvido essa.

Comment: Ok, bom teres achado o problema. Fechei a pergunta pois o problema não tinha a ver com a pergunta aqui. Até breve.